# Firebase import error on 'import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";' in firebase version 10.3.1 installed via npm

Tags: javascript, firebase, syntax-error, importerror

I want to use the new firebase modular API (as named in the docs) for my project. I installed firebase from terminal via `npm install firebase` (as in the docs). That created 2 files 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' and a folder, namely 'node_modules'

then to start using firebase, in my app.js file i wrote the following code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  //My firebase config
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

[Docs Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0)

while opening my html file with just this piece  of js and simple html, linking the js file.....I get this error in the console

[image: Error given out]

I looked across the Internet and other stack overflow questions but couldn't get a fix,

and yes I have tried changing

`import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";`

to

`import initializeApp from "firebase/app";`

Still it didn't fix the issue, instead the new error was

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'initializeApp'. import call
> expects exactly one argument.

Im using firebase version 10.3.1 (as I deduce from the package.json file that was auto created after doing `npm install firebase`)..Here is what it is

[image]

Im also getting the same syntax error from the other thing I have tried to import like the realtime database  and authentication ones
Your help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine to use `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"`

The issue is how you link the app.js file from the html. The solution is to add `type="module"` as an attribute to the script tag.

This article explains it well:
https://javascript.info/modules-intro

Currently import statements are only available in ES6 modules.

Comment: Thanks a ton, although now I have imported firebase things from the CDN way, but now I have another problem...I created a function signup, but when I pass that function in onClick in html document I get the error that can't find variable signUp(). Could you please help me out on that

[Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77094539/14379683)