# "Cant find variable" error when function is passed in a onClick event in html, Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, function

I am using firebase for my web project. I have configured the firebase app and then imported the js script where I configured the app into my html doc as a `type=module` then I have written a `function signUp()` in the js file. I have added a button in the html doc with `onClick = "signUp()"` (this has worked for me in all of my past project where I used the old firebase SDK), but I'm getting an error that `can't find variable signUp()`

JS FILE:

[image]

HTMl Code (button and importing app.js)

[image]

The error

[image]

I have imported the app.js file as a module since importing the firebase modules requires me to do so and it won't/doesn't work without importing app.js as a type module

I also tried moving the function to another separate file but then there I dont have access to the createUserWithEmailAndPassword and other function so that's also not working

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `app.js` under your signUp() function

```
window.signUp = signUp
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but what does it exactly do and could you also tell me why wasn't it working without this, I mean it used to work before

Comment: @AshmeetSIngh It is used when you want to make the function accessible from global scope so that it can be called from anywhere in your JavaScript code, including HTML attributes like onclick. This can be helpful in larger applications where you may have scripts in different files or modules.

Comment: Just to explain a little more just in case, the type="module" on the script tag limits the scope hence why you have to make it accessible from the the global scope

Comment: @cub It would be great if you can provide any other solution beside accessing it as a global scope. Thank in advance

Comment: @PanhaBot yours seems fine if that's what they want. Firebase requires the Module because of the imports it does, if a script isn't a module, that doesn't work. Modules can still access elements on the DOM still, so you could always just setup the click event in the module rather than the HTML, it only just means if you reuse it somewhere else it needs the same selector.

Comment: the module added in the HTML is supposed to be the top level module, in which you import other modules. So you could make a separate module, that sets up the click event on the page, and it imports your firebase module functions, that way your firebase module can be easily reused.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want add it to the global scope like @PanhaBot's suggestion. just setup the click event in the app.js. If you need to reuse the fireBase stuff else where, put that into a separate module and import that into app.js.

```
const b = document.querySelector('#myButton');
b.addEventListener("click", signUp);

<button id="myButton"></button>
```

[here is a simple tutorial](https://javascript.info/modules-intro) that might shed some light on how modules work in a basic way without a bundler. Here is also [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590393/es6-modules-undefined-onclick-function-after-import) that is similar to yours that may help you understand.

Notice in the first example they write a function in sayHi.js and then that module is imported in main.js. The next step in their example just uses a inline script, but that could be replaced with `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>`. So in context to yours it would be similar, a js file for firebase stuff, then you could import that into a main.js to actually use it somewhere.

It should also be known that when using js modules, people prefer to use a bundler, as it can make things simpler if your project is bigger as well as give you performance optimizations. The main idea of a bundler is that your bundler gives you a single bundled file to deliver, rather than many files for each module.

[here is a firebase example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/module-bundling) of using npm and webpack to bundle. Some may consider webpack to be kind of out of date in terms of modern bundlers, but if you have never used a bundler before I don't think its personally a bad place to start as there is a lot of information about how to use it.

If your just messing around then to get something working, then your probably fine without a bundler, but like [this fireBase tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) states under step 2, `Using browser modules is a quick way to get started, but we recommend using a module bundler for production.`. In context to your firebase example, at a minimum it would remove your dependency on the gstatic url to get firebase modules as you would install them yourself using a package manager like npm or yarn.

Comment: could you tell me the firebase reuse thing...from what I understood u r saying to make a separate file with the firebase config and initialise and then the functions in another js file and I will then. only need to import the js file with the function init

Comment: see edit in post above. hope that helps.